# Objective-C: Set boolean value in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsunknownkeyexception

In my data model, in an entity, I have an attribute that is a boolean.  In the xcmodeldatad file, it is listed as:

`need sync Boolean.`  In the NSmanagedobject file it is as follows:

```
.h file: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *needsync;//bool
.m file @dynamic needsync;
```

When saving the record after an edit, I use the following code that I have used numerous times before:

[list setValue:@0 forKey:@"needsync"];

However, it is throwing an exception when it reaches this line of

```
NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x17409c4d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key need sync.'
```

This is really baffling me and I wonder if anyone can spot error or has had this happen before.

Thank you.

Comment: NSNumber *num = @([@"0" intValue]);
[list setValue: num forKey:@"needsync"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your code again.

The crash log shows that your object is a NSString, instead of YourList object, so, it doesn't has needsync property => crash.

Comment: Turns out I had an NSStringnamed list as well as an NSManagedObject named list.  Sometimes the compiler was able to figure out which was which but in this case it did not.

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of your `list` dictionary? Is it `NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, NSNumber*>` ? If so then you might have mismatched type between your ***Entity Attribute*** and ***Property Declaration***.

Or if your dictionary is of type `NSMutableDictionary<NSNumber*, NSNumber*>` then try this:

```
[list setObject:@0 forKey:needsync]; // don't make `needsync` a NSString* object, it's already an object type (NSNumber*)
```